# Connect to MQTT broker through UART 802.15.4

Tags: c, mqtt, xbee, socat

I am just trying to run a mqtt client with a Xbee S2C in a RaspberryPi (connected via UART) with a mqtt broker on my laptop that has another XBee S2C connected with a FTDI. I am using MQTT Paho library to run the program, but this has the problem that you can not send the messages via uart, so I am writting this messages to a localhost port and try to read and link them with the uart as follow

```
sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:1881 PTY, link=/dev/ttyAMA0
```

Where 1881 is the local port where I am publishing my messages and /dev/ttyAMA0 is the uart connection to the XBee devide in the RPI.

Then, I am running on my laptop

```
sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyUSB0 TCP:localhost:1881
```

Where /dev/ttyUSB0 y the serial port where my XBee device is connected to the broker and 1881 the local port where I have my broker.

But this ends in no messages and no connection when I try to run my script with the MQTT example. I now that the port numbers are properly set because I have been able to send messages in transparent mode between both XBee devices, so I do not know what is happening here...

Thanks.

Comment: You have a fairly complicated setup, and you need to isolate the problem to identify what might be going wrong.  If you just open the serial port on both devices, does text flow between them?  If you use `socat` on one side but a terminal emulator on the other, do you see the messages?  If you place a logic probe on the Tx/Rx pins of the XBee, do you see data flowing when expected?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @tomlogic ! I solved the problem with a C socket script. I had data without in the normal configuration, so I do not know why I could not stablish communication with socat. But with the new setup I can run the program without too much problem.